# Issue with for in Scala Processing

Tags: scala, oop, applet, functional-programming

In the code below, when I try `i = i + 10` it will not compile, with error `cannot reassign to val`. So I added `var i = 0;` before the `for`, but the variable is never used:

```
var i = 0;
for(i <- 5 to 25) {
    i = i + 10
    ellipse(150, 150, tamano + i, tamano + i)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with some of the Scala idioms by going through an online Scala tutorial.  That will cover this type of issue.

When you use `for` in Scala, a new `val` is created in each loop.  In your example, the `i` in the `for` is shadowing the outer `var i`, which will never be used.

In Scala, `vals` cannot be reassigned.  You can always assign a new `val` by doing:

```
val j = i + 10
```

And then using `j`.

This code is far from idiomatic Scala, which is based heavily in the idea of immutability.  You could try something like the following:

```
for(i <- 5 to 25 by 10) {
    ellipse(150, 150, tamano + i, tamano + i)
}
```

Or:

```
(5 to 25 by 10).foreach { i =>
    ellipse(150, 150, tamano + i, tamano + i)
}
```

Also note that `to` and `by` are just syntactic sugar for the methods on the `Range` object:

```
Range.inclusive(start = 5, end = 25, step = 10) == (5 to 25 by 10) //true
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, could you recommend some good Scala tutorial?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this looks reasonable: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaTutorial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

That's because `i` is a `val`, since it is the argument to the function passed to `foreach` (which is what your `for` comprehension de-sugars to):

```
for(i <- 5 to 25) {
  doWorkWith(i)
}
```

becomes:

```
(5 to 25).forEach(i => doWorkWith(i))
```

Arguments are immutable, so you cannot re-assign `i`.

The solution here is to use another name for your intermediate value:

```
for(i <- 5 to 25) {
    val offset = i + 10
    ellipse(150, 150, tamano + offset, tamano + offset)
}
```

(Alternatively, in this case, you can just change your range from `5 to 25` to `15 to 35` and avoid the extra addition)